# Merge two lines in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to write a pig script for below query.

Input is:

```
ABC,DEF,,
,,GHI,JKL
MNO,PQR,,
,,STU,VWX
```

Output should be:

```
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL
MNO,PQR,STU,VWX
```

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: I have used cross join and cubes as well but unable to solve it.

Comment: Is it your input is fixed format? ie 1st row last two cols will be null, 2nd row first two cols will be null, 3rd row last two cols will be null ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be difficult to solve this problem using native pig. One option could be download the `datafu-1.2.0.jar` library and try the below approach.

**input.txt**

```
ABC,DEF,,
,,GHI,JKL
MNO,PQR,,
,,STU,VWX
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER /tmp/datafu-1.2.0.jar;
DEFINE BagSplit datafu.pig.bags.BagSplit();

A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(f1,f2,f3,f4);
B = GROUP A ALL;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(BagSplit(2,$1)) AS mybag;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(REPLACE(BagToString(mybag),'_null_null_null_null',''),'_',4));
E = FOREACH D GENERATE $2,$3,$0,$1;
DUMP E;
```

**Output:**

```
(MNO,PQR,STU,VWX)
(ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL)
```

**Note:**
Based on the above input format, my assumption will be 1st row last two cols will be null, 2nd row first two cols will be null, similarly for 3rd and 4th row also

Comment: output of above script is : {(null,null,STU,VWX_MNO_PQR_null_null)
(null,null,GHI,JKL_ABC_DEF_null_null)}

Comment: It is working fine for me and i got the expected output. Can you paste your pig script and also the input?

Comment: Thanks for answering Siva. That was not woking for me. I have edited your answer but still output is not as expected.

Comment: You are changing the null string format, don't do like that it will not work. you want to print the output as $2,$3,$0,$1 right?

Comment: Yes I want output as $0,$1,$2,$3. If i am not changing null string format then it's showing _null as well. Please suggest

Comment: i modified the same code, just copy paste the input and run the above script. it will work.

Comment: I have just put two replace for _null and null_ in D. It is working fine. Thanks a ton