# Merge Line in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to write a pig script for below query.

Input is:

```
AAA,,,
,BBB,,
,,,DDD
AAA,,,
,BBB,,
,,CCC,
,,,DDD
AAA,,,
,BBB,,
,,,DDD
```

Output should be:

```
AAA,BBB,,DDD
AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD
AAA,BBB,,DDD
```

I have tried with [Merge two lines in Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628171/merge-two-lines-in-pig/27630682) but if i am trying to split bag BagSplit(3,$1) then output is not correct because my output will be merge of first three lines and then next four lines and again next three lines

The inputs may be increase but one important thing that last line would always be ,,,DDD .

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your input data should be split into different lengths(3,4,3), so `BagSplit` function will not work in this case. Can you try the below approach? The duplicated part of relation `E  (TOTUPLE)` can be further optimized using `MACROS` but it will leads to more confusion, so i didn't optimize as of now.

**input.txt**

```
AAA,,,
,BBB,,
,,,DDD
AAA,,,
,BBB,,
,,CCC,
,,,DDD
AAA,,,
,BBB,,
,,,DDD
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(f1,f2,f3,f4);
B = RANK A;
C = GROUP B ALL;
D = FOREACH C  {
                 firstRecord = FILTER B BY rank_A<=3;                /* store first 3 records*/
                 secondRecord= FILTER B BY rank_A>3 AND rank_A<=7;   /* store next 4 records */
                 thirdRecord = FILTER B BY rank_A>7;                 /* store next 3 records */
                 GENERATE firstRecord,secondRecord,thirdRecord;
                }

/* Convert each split bags(firstRecord,secondRecord and thirdRecord) into strings and replace 'null' and '_' with  empty characters.*/
E = FOREACH D GENERATE FLATTEN(TOBAG(
                                        TOTUPLE(REPLACE(BagToString(firstRecord.f1),'[null|_]',''),
                                                REPLACE(BagToString(firstRecord.f2),'[null|_]',''),
                                                REPLACE(BagToString(firstRecord.f3),'[null|_]',''),
                                                REPLACE(BagToString(firstRecord.f4),'[null|_]','')),
                                        TOTUPLE(REPLACE(BagToString(secondRecord.f1),'[null|_]',''),
                                                REPLACE(BagToString(secondRecord.f2),'[null|_]',''),
                                                REPLACE(BagToString(secondRecord.f3),'[null|_]',''),
                                                REPLACE(BagToString(secondRecord.f4),'[null|_]','')),
                                        TOTUPLE(REPLACE(BagToString(thirdRecord.f1),'[null|_]',''),
                                                REPLACE(BagToString(thirdRecord.f2),'[null|_]',''),
                                                REPLACE(BagToString(thirdRecord.f3),'[null|_]',''),
                                                REPLACE(BagToString(thirdRecord.f4),'[null|_]',''))
                                        )
                                 );
DUMP E;
```

**Output:**

```
(AAA,BBB,,DDD)
(AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD)
(AAA,BBB,,DDD)
```

Comment: But I am not sure about length. It might be 3,3,4 but last line should be ,,, DDD.  Please let me know how can we solve this

Comment: If you don't know the length in advance then it will be difficult to solve this problem. Once option could you go for custom UDF and tweak the output inside the UDF.